# Swift - Delete cell from UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, nsdocumentdirectory

I am following this code to remove data from `UITableView`

```
var recordedAudioFilesURLArray = [URL]()
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .delete {
            recordedAudioFilesURLArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
```

When I swipe left to a particular cell, the cell remove from `UITableView`. Thats great. But when I close my app and again relaunch my app, deleted cells are appeared.
**Audio Files are stored in Document Directory.**

Comment: This code the element from the array but you need to also delete the file or whatever is used to load data *into* the array when your app starts

Comment: Then you need to also delete that file from document directory.

Comment: You also need to remove this file from document directory as well.because you are justing removing element from array , but not removing actual file.once you fill data again it also load whole data again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use that `URL` array to remove the file from `DocumentDirectory` then remove the object from `Array`.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {

        //First remove file from DocumentDirectory
        try? FileManager.default.removeItem(at: recordedAudioFilesURLArray[indexPath.row]) 

        //Remove object from array
        recordedAudioFilesURLArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)

        //Reload tableView
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        recordedAudioFilesURLArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        self. clearAllFilesFromTempDirectory(indexPath.row);
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}

func clearAllFilesFromTempDirectory()->fullPath
 {

        if fileManager.removeItemAtPath(fullPath, error: error) == false 
        {
            println("delete successfully")
        }


  else 
       {
         println("Could not retrieve directory: \(error)")
       }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
objects.remove(at: 0)
let indexPath = IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0)
tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, and thank you for contributing an answer. Would you kindly edit your answer to to include an explanation of your code? That will help future readers better understand what is going on, and especially those members of the community who are new to the language and struggling to understand the concepts. That's especially important when there's already an accepted answer that's been validated by the community. Under what conditions might your approach be preferred? Are you taking advantage of new capabilities?